# Где я ошибся, не могу понять

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Запускаю команду от которой ожидаю что если файл существует то он переместиться в папку save

```
$ (if [ -f "new.sql" ]; then mv new.sql save/$(date +%s).sql; exit 33; fi);
```

Получаю сообщение об ошибке

> $ (if [ -f "new.sql" ]; then mv new.sql save/$(date +%s).sql; exit 33;
>   fi); mesg: ttyname failed: Invalid argument ERROR: Job failed: Process
>   exited with: 1. Reason was:  ()

Comment: хоть бы комментарий перед тем как дизлайкать, что не так с вопросом?

Comment: @D-side поправил вопрос, так понятнее?

Comment: Добавте проверку lsof на вашу базу, если она активна и вы ее двинете, не гарантированно, что переместится корректно.

Comment: @Hellseher спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вроде

```
ls new.sql && mv new.sql save/$(date +%s).sql
```

Comment: спасибо попробую